# Painting a cube

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, cube

I have took this example and I want to make a solid black cube, any ideas how can I add some color to the sides of the cube?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product, combinations
from numpy import sin, cos


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("auto")
ax.set_autoscale_on(True)


#dibujar cubo
r = [-10, 10]
for s, e in combinations(np.array(list(product(r,r,r))), 2):
    if np.sum(np.abs(s-e)) == r[1]-r[0]:
        ax.plot3D(*zip(s,e), color="b")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a collection of definitions to generate a parametric cube within Matplotlib. It is more complex than your snippet and could be done in a compact way, but this implementation offers quite some flexibility like arbitrary segments count, faces exclusion, etc...

More informations (like docstrings) are available in [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/develop/colour/plotting/geometry.py) repository.

```py
# Required import for following computations.
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show


def quad(plane='xy', origin=None, width=1, height=1, depth=0):
    u, v = (0, 0) if origin is None else origin

    plane = plane.lower()
    if plane == 'xy':
        vertices = ((u, v, depth),
                    (u + width, v, depth),
                    (u + width, v + height, depth),
                    (u, v + height, depth))
    elif plane == 'xz':
        vertices = ((u, depth, v),
                    (u + width, depth, v),
                    (u + width, depth, v + height),
                    (u, depth, v + height))
    elif plane == 'yz':
        vertices = ((depth, u, v),
                    (depth, u + width, v),
                    (depth, u + width, v + height),
                    (depth, u, v + height))
    else:
        raise ValueError('"{0}" is not a supported plane!'.format(plane))

    return np.array(vertices)


def grid(plane='xy',
         origin=None,
         width=1,
         height=1,
         depth=0,
         width_segments=1,
         height_segments=1):
    u, v = (0, 0) if origin is None else origin

    w_x, h_y = width / width_segments, height / height_segments

    quads = []
    for i in range(width_segments):
        for j in range(height_segments):
            quads.append(
                quad(plane, (i * w_x + u, j * h_y + v), w_x, h_y, depth))

    return np.array(quads)


def cube(plane=None,
         origin=None,
         width=1,
         height=1,
         depth=1,
         width_segments=1,
         height_segments=1,
         depth_segments=1):
    plane = (('+x', '-x', '+y', '-y', '+z', '-z')
             if plane is None else
             [p.lower() for p in plane])
    u, v, w = (0, 0, 0) if origin is None else origin

    w_s, h_s, d_s = width_segments, height_segments, depth_segments

    grids = []
    if '-z' in plane:
        grids.extend(grid('xy', (u, w), width, depth, v, w_s, d_s))
    if '+z' in plane:
        grids.extend(grid('xy', (u, w), width, depth, v + height, w_s, d_s))

    if '-y' in plane:
        grids.extend(grid('xz', (u, v), width, height, w, w_s, h_s))
    if '+y' in plane:
        grids.extend(grid('xz', (u, v), width, height, w + depth, w_s, h_s))

    if '-x' in plane:
        grids.extend(grid('yz', (w, v), depth, height, u, d_s, h_s))
    if '+x' in plane:
        grids.extend(grid('yz', (w, v), depth, height, u + width, d_s, h_s))

    return np.array(grids)


canvas = figure()
axes = Axes3D(canvas)

quads = cube(width_segments=4, height_segments=4, depth_segments=4)

# You can replace the following line by whatever suits you. Here, we compute
# each quad colour by averaging its vertices positions.
RGB = np.average(quads, axis=-2)
# Setting +xz and -xz plane faces to black.
RGB[RGB[..., 1] == 0] = 0
RGB[RGB[..., 1] == 1] = 0
# Adding an alpha value to the colour array.
RGBA = np.hstack((RGB, np.full((RGB.shape[0], 1), .85)))

collection = Poly3DCollection(quads)
collection.set_color(RGBA)
axes.add_collection3d(collection)

show()
```

[image: Matplotlib - Parametric Cube]